# Unable to remove NaN values from my function in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, nan

The purpose of this function is to remove the white spaces of a given String, then convert it into a Number, and finally push each    character of the number into an empty array (i.e. "24532", should push into the array the following [2,4,5,3,2]). However, when I console my output array at the end of the function -- I receive NaN values in the output array. Each step in the function is making sense for me, but I'm not sure where my mistake is living. Any help will be appreciated!

```
function convert(numbers){
   var notString = parseInt(numbers.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10),
   sNumber = notString.toString(),
   output =[];

   console.log(sNumber);

     for(var i = 0; i < sNumber.length; i+=1) {
       output.push(+sNumber.charAt[i]);    

   }
    console.log(output);

   } 

   convert("1 2 2 2 2");
```

Comment: The problem is that you have `[]` after `charAt` instead of `()`. So it should be `+sNumber.charAt(i)`. Now it calls the function instead of accessing a property on it.

Comment: The expression "sNumber.charAt[i]" is undefined.  (Javascript does not mind that you're trying to dereference a function).  The unary plus operator is attempting to convert undefined into a number and producing NaN and pushing that into your array.   (`push(+sNumber.charAt[i]) ~~> push(+undefined) ~~> push(NaN)`).  Your example actually ends up with an array of 5 x NaN

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `String#split()`?

```js
function convert(numbers) {
    return numbers.trim().split(/\s+/).map(Number);
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(convert("   1 2 2 2 2  "), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: That's the way to go, except that you should `.trim()` the string before splitting. +1

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this

```
function convert(numbers){
  return numbers.replace(/\s+/g,'').split('');
}

console.log(convert("1 2 2 2 2"));
```

Actually, if it always is only 1 space character, you can do like this

```
console.log("1 2 2 2 2".split(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps
    https://jsfiddle.net/x0mubx4q/

```
output.push(sNumber[i]);
```

The problem is with .chartAt() function. This will return a string.

Comment: Yeah, you can use + sign for a number. it will work now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the + before sNumber in the push instatement.  Also instead of console.log use console.dir

```
    function convert(numbers){
      var arystrNumbers = numbers.split(" "), aryNumbers = [];

      for( var idx in arystrNumbers ) {
         aryNumbers.push(parseInt(arystrNumbers[idx]));    
      }
      return aryNumbers;  
    };


    console.log("Before: " + strNumbers);
    console.dir(convert("1 2 2 2 2"));
```

Try the above.

Comment: Why would he remove the `+`? That's needed right there.

Comment: For what purpose? It isn't required.  It should read: output.push(sNumber[i]);

Comment: For the same purpose for which you added `parseInt()` to your answer. `output.push(sNumber[i])` pushes a string to the array. The `+` converts it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `split` function as said @Nina, but if you are interested in where is your error, you can try this:

Replace

```
charAt[i]
```

to

```
charAt(i) // parentheses
```

`charAt` is a function and you need to use parentheses `()` to call it